# Typo3 multiple sitemap for multdomain in one typo3 instance

Tags: xml, .htaccess, seo, typo3

In my typo3 instance i have a **main domain** which is already gone live and now i have multiple domains configured and for each domain i would like to generate a seperate sitemap.xml with links configured in each domains

My situation is 
Created Page Sitemap -> Created Menu and Sitemap from special menu
(Working with Template )-> Created a template for my sitemap page and put content which generates the sitemap for me.

Problem is
when i call subdomain/sitemap.xml it generates sitemap.xml with all the url in the **main domain** and sub domain

from my research i found out some suggestions which are
Can i solve it with real url or i must generate sitemap for each domain through my php script or can htaccess help in this case
something like

`<url><loc>http://domain1/index.php?id=test</loc><lastmod>2015-11-26T15:45:37+01:00</lastmod><changefreq>weekly</changefreq><priority>0.5</priority></url>` and so on

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: i have solved it with dd_googlesitemap where i specify the tx_ddgooglesitemap.forceStartPid = rootid of each domain

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post. But now you can easily set this up with the Extension [cs_seo](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/cs_seo). More information in german are available on [this blog page](https://www.clickstorm.de/blog/sitemap-xml-robots-txt-typo3-cs_seo/).